# Moving a worksflow from site to site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have two SharePoint 2010 environments which are nearly identical (dev/prod).

I have a workflow in dev that I need to recreate in prod. How do I upload/transfer/publish the workflow that's in the dev site to the prod site?

The workflow is in SharePoint Designer

Comment: is it designer workflow or VS workflow or OOTB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you designed your workflow in SharePoint Designer.

Here's an article that might help you to move your workflow:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflows_for_product_catalogs/archive/2012/11/02/deploying-a-workflow-on-a-different-server.aspx

The pre-requisite is that the workflow needs to have been created as a re-usable workflow. Although the article talks about SharePoint 2013, you may find the solution is similar with SharePoint 2010.

Comment: I take it there's no way to convert a List Workflow to a Reusable Workflow?

Comment: It seems there is :) http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/10/converting-a-list-workflow-to-a-re-usable-workflow/ . But first check that you can't save your workflow as a template without having to do this.

Comment: That's what I like to see!